# Changing Text Element Leading Causes Position Changes

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have several maps I need to update that have a long list of text contained in a single text element. I wanted to vertically compress the text, while retaining the font size. The problem is if the leading is set to anything other than 0, the entire text body moves position on its own whenever I pan around in layout view.

Is there a setting I am missing that could be causing this? Or is this a known bug?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include screenshots (before and after) to illustrate your problem, and one showing the settings you are changing.